# Consider the predator prey model and make change of variables to put it in dimensionless form.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have this predator-prey model 
\begin{align*} 
\frac{dH}{dt} &= rH \left(1-\frac{H}{K} \right) - \alpha \frac{PH}{H+ \beta}  \\ 
\frac{dP}{dt} &= \gamma P \left( -1+ \delta \frac{H}{H+ \beta} \right)
\end{align*}
And I am asked to make the following change of variables to put the model in dimensionless form.
$$x=\frac{H}{K}, \ \ y=\frac{\alpha}{rK}P, \ \ \text{and} \ \ \tau=rt.$$
Then
\begin{align*}
\frac{dx}{d \tau} &= x \left(1-x-\frac{y}{x+b} \right) \\
\frac{dy}{d \tau} &= cy \left(-1+a\frac{x}{x+b} \right)
\end{align*}
Can someone give me a HINT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is very easy. It's just replacing of variables and constants by new variables and constants, and the chain rule, of course. For example,
$${dx\over d\tau}={1\over K}\>{dH\over d\tau}={1\over K}\>{dH/dt\over d\tau/dt}={1\over Kr}\>{dH\over dt}=\ldots\quad.$$
Now plug in the right side from your first equation, and express everything in terms of the new variables/constants. Same thing with the second equation.